# Database of words that differ by one phoneme

Tags: phonemes, minimal-pairs

I want to test whether people are able to distinguish different phonemes from each other.

Example:
men (/mɛn/) and man (/mæn/)

The user of the software is supposed to hear the correct pronunciation and then decide which of the two choices he heard. 
I'm searching for a good list of word pairs that especially covers sound pairs that are hard to distinguish.

I don't care about the language of the words as long as the resource clearly lists IPA and I can somehow access an audio file with the correct pronunciation.

Comment: What you are looking for is a list of *minimal pairs*.

Comment: "People" in general are not able to "distinguish different phonemes from each other", **unless** they are native speakers of the language the phonemes are from. There is no such thing as "the phoneme /a/" in general; there is only the English phoneme /a/, the Malay phoneme /a/, etc. So you **hafta** care about the language of the words, because only native speakers of that language can be expected to tell the phonemes apart.

Comment: You may want to take a look at this http://myweb.tiscali.co.uk/wordscape/wordlist/minimal.html

Comment: And just to add to what @jlawler has said, native speakers of a language can (in normal situations) by definition distinguish different phonemes of that language because that's what makes them different phonemes (ignoring things such as the McGurk effect).

Comment: @jlawler: Then there is [the view that there is no such thing as the phoneme at all](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/212/is-the-very-concept-of-the-phoneme-disputed), not even the English phoneme /a/ and the Malay phoneme /a/ etc. Doesn't mean these concepts are not useful in both senses.

Comment: Of course; "phonemes" and "morphemes" and "words" and "clauses" -- not to mention "Equi" and "Merge" -- are terms used to **describe** phenomena, not phenomena per se. But so are "force" and "mass" and "acceleraton", and it would be hard to talk about physical phenomena without them.