# Resource for German minimal pairs

Tags: phonemes, resource-request, german, minimal-pairs

I recently asked a [general question about minimal pairs](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/8558/database-of-words-that-differ-by-one-phoneme) and got a link to a [website](http://myweb.tiscali.co.uk/wordscape/wordlist/minimal.html) that provides a comprehensive list of English minimal pairs.

Is there a similar list for German minimal pairs?

Answer (score 2):

The German word for minimal pair is Minimalpaar: [de Wikipedia article](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimalpaar)

You can then search for examples using that word. Here is one slideshow I encountered:
[Phonologie](http://www.germsem.uni-kiel.de/ndnl/materialien/wintersemester0910/Einf%20Sprwiss%204%20-%20Phonologie.pdf)

Some examples are:
mahlen, zahlen, kahlen, fahlen, ...

Answer (score 1):

The book of Siebs, *Deutsche Aussprache* (19th printing 2000) contains a list of relevant minimal pairs and some almost minimal pairs that define the different phonemes of standard High German.