# Is a diphthong one phoneme or two, or does it depend?

Tags: phonetics, phonology, terminology, phonemes, diphthongs

In [Mitch's answer to ***"What is the difference between a diphthong and a glide?"***](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/a/1147/51) and its comments it seems more than one of us is at least a bit confused as to how many ***phonemes*** a single ***diphthong*** represents:

1. The two vowel sounds in a diphthong combine to make a single phoneme.
2. A diphthong is a sequence of two phonemes of a certain kind in a certain relationship.
3. Sometimes the two sounds of a diphthong are considered to be one phoneme, but sometimes they are each considered separate phonemes, depending on context or something else.

So which of these possibilities is true? And if **3.** is true, what are the things that make it one or two phonemes?

Answer (score 5):

1. A diphthong is one sound segment created by a smooth transition between two targets within the same syllable. As a phonetic definition, this makes no theoretical claims about which phoneme(s) represent the articulation in the mind of the speaker.
2. This statement is a bit vague, but is, as far as I can tell, true in some situations; see below.
3. The number and character of underlying phonemes that a diphthong corresponds to varies by language and which researcher you talk to. Different kinds of evidence for a particular interpretation of field data are evaluated differently by each specialists, and mainstream phonology has yet to produce a theoretical framework that gives one clear answer to this question for each language.

   In English, for example, the diphthong [e͡ɪ] could be represented underlyingly as either the single phoneme /e͡ɪ/ or a sequence of two phonemes /ej/, where /j/ is the same segment that appears in /jɛs/ "yes". The latter analysis is tempting, since it would reduce the size of the phonemic inventory (all possible underlying segments) of English, but would have to explain the phonetic differences between the /j/ in "yes" and the /j/ in "made", which is much more like an [ɪ]. Of course, the addition of a transformation rule would be standard practice when faced with this situation, but we are then left with the basic question of which is simpler (and thus, more likely to be adopted as a strategy by native speakers): fewer phonemes, or fewer rules?

Comment: So, how do you determine whether a particular segment is a phoneme or not? How many phonemes can you find in the word "made"?

Comment: if you have such a concept (the phoneme) in a phonological theory you subscribe to.

Comment: An excellent question - this has been alluded to before in answers [here](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/301/when-should-one-use-slashes-or-square-brackets-when-transcribing-in-ipa/304) and [here](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/342/how-to-determine-which-phoneme-a-group-of-allophones-realize/343), but the time has probably come for this to be posted as a top-level question, perhaps titled something like "How is phonemic analysis performed?", maybe with "on an undocumented language" at the end.

Comment: I will answer with a brief overview of generative phonology, which I was taught as an undergrad and remains in the mainstream, and which I enthusiastically disagree with. Spoiler alert: there is no theoretical limit to the number of phonemes that the word "made" can be composed of.

Comment: @hippietrail, I appreciate your efforts to make the site a bit more user-friendly, but nitpicking everyone's commenting style is only going to clutter threads with replies irrelevant to the discussion at hand, discourage new users from posting again for fear they'll be pounced on for breaking another unknown "rule", and will ultimately be unable to keep up with the constant influx of new users.

Comment: This answer makes me wonder further where the term *segment* stands in relation to *phone* and *phoneme*.

Comment: @hippietrail It decreases the signal-to-noise ratio of the comments. And that is a great question; I was wondering whether someone would ask that. The answer I started typing quickly became too long - could you post that as a top-level question?

Comment: It sounds like an interesting forthcoming question. Keep in mind that generative phonologists early on become notorious for trying to *abolish* the phoneme.

Comment: Yes in fact one of my early questions here was on that very topic: **[Is the very concept of the phoneme disputed?](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/212/is-the-very-concept-of-the-phoneme-disputed)**

Comment: OK I asked [a new question about what segments are and how they fit in the picture with phones and phonemes](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/1158/where-does-the-term-segment-fit-in-in-relation-to-phone-and-phoneme).

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with no.1 because you can find the following minimal pairs in English (RP):

could - cowed /ʊ/ versus /aʊ/

cheese - cheers /i/ versus /ɪə/

dead-dared /e/ versus /eə/

bell-bail /e/ versus /eɪ/

buy - boy /aɪ/ versus /ɔɪ/
etc.

For a comprehensive list of minimal pairs in English (RP) compiled by John Higgins, see http://myweb.tiscali.co.uk/wordscape/wordlist/index.html

Thus, **a single diphthong in English represents one phoneme.**

This is traditional phonology, *not* generative.

Naturally, other analyses have been proposed, too. For example, a diphthong is treated as a vowel plus a semivowel or another vowel (McCarthy 1952). Thus, **you end up having a diphthong consisting of two phonemes under those approaches**. [Peter Roach (2009)](http://books.google.com/books?id=dDVR_zh5wkMC&lpg=PP1&dq=peter%20roach%20english&pg=PP1#v=onepage&q=peter%20roach%20english&f=false) mentions that this view was "almost universally accepted by American (and some British) writers from the 1940s to the 1960s, and *still pervades contemporary American descriptions*" (p. 104). [Roger Lass (1984)](http://books.google.com/books?id=aTsAt3D6H58C&lpg=PP1&dq=lass%20phonology&pg=PP1#v=onepage&q&f=false) argues that analyzing a diphthong as a vowel plus a semivowel /j/ or /w/ is a "shaky position" (p. 138). He also convincingly dismisses the approach proposed in SPE (Chomsky and Halle), characterizing it as "seem[ing] **close to lunacy**" (p. 138). [Bruce Hayes (2008)](http://books.google.com/books?id=QT8W4zDHKvwC&lpg=PP1&dq=bruce%20hayes&pg=PT1#v=onepage&q=bruce%20hayes&f=false) concludes that the "fewer-phonemes-the-better" analysis is not an iron-clad argument and that **the segment/sequence problem** is still "an unsettled one in phonology" (p. 57).

Comment: You've provided the right answer to the wrong question. This data set shows that English diphthongs are *phonemically distinct* from their monophthongal (or short, or lax) "counterparts" (except for the last pair) - it says nothing about how many segments are stored in an English speaker's mental phonological system.

Comment: I'm afraid I didn't make myself clear enough. The question is poorly phrased since it is based on the wrong assumption that phonematicity of a diphthong might depend on phonematicity of its structural segments. I would like to emphasize that whether parts of a diphthong are phonemes or not in a particular language is irrelevant for determining phonematicity of a diphthong itself.

Comment: I welcome answers that clearly illustrate what might be wrong in the question, especially if they include references. (phonematicity is an interesting word by the way. I'd never heard of it before and it gets only 48 Google hits including some for "Phone, MATI CITY".)

Comment: In traditional phonology (not generative), you need minimal pairs to determine whether you're dealing with allophones of the same phoneme or two different phonemes (see some minimal pairs in my answer above). You can read about it in any undergrad textbook Re: the word "phonematicity", it may not be widely used but I'm in no way the first one who used it in the sense of "the state of being a phoneme".

Comment: I stand corrected, there is another, more usual, term, phonemicity.

Comment: This answer makes me wonder whether minimal pairs are (or ought to be) based on phonemes, phones, or segments...

Comment: Well, minimal pairs are based on one type (phones) to show that those can also be asserted as another higher-level type (phonemes), seeing as in this (very restrictive) approach they are the means of determining phonemicity. (Segment can be used for both phone and phoneme, but is often used to avoid committing to these notions.)

Comment: You said "bell-bail /e/ versus /eɪ/". Isn't bell pronounced as /bɛl/ while bail as /beɪl/? There are no common vowels.

Comment: @ Robin, it depends on your dialect. Some pronounce "bell" as [bɛl], some as [bel] (like me).

Comment: And yes, I am aware of Schmitt 2007, The case for the epsilon (ε) symbol in PR dress, http://journals.cambridge.org/abstract_S0025100307003131

Answer (score 1):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diphthong

Here is what I used the last time I searched for the same thing before this website. Diphthongs are considered one phoneme with two targets, meaning the tongue moves during the pronunciation of the vowel.

Comment: Interestingly, the Wikipedia article now says, "In some languages, diphthongs are single phonemes, while in others they are analyzed as sequences of two vowels, or of a vowel and a semivowel." Elsewhere it references http://www-01.sil.org/linguistics/GlossaryOfLinguisticTerms/WhatIsADiphthong.htm to say, "Diphthongs often form when separate vowels are run together in rapid speech during a conversation. However, there are also unitary diphthongs, as in the English examples above, which are heard by listeners as single-vowel sounds (phonemes)."

Comment: I love Wiki more than anyone, it's so useful, insightful...BUT you should NOT cite wikipedia.