# Hang Sơn Đoòng — the syllable Đoòng in Vietnamese orthography

Tags: orthography, vietnamese

There's a cave in Vietnam which has been newly opened to tourism called [Hang Sơn Đoòng](http://vi.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hang_S%C6%A1n_%C4%90o%C3%B2ng) ([English Wikipedia article here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Son_Doong_cave)).

My question is about the syllable in the name of the cave which is represented as `đoòng`. I didn't think the orthography allowed a nucleus written as `oo`, but it's there in the Vietnamese version of the page as well.

Also, the only matches for `đoòng` that I can find are references to the cave. Is this a possible nucleus in Vietnamese orthography, and if so, what does it represent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a licit nucleus, transcribed -ɔŋ in Nguyen-Dinh Hoa's *Vietnamese-English Dictionary* (1966), Charles E. Tuttle Company. In the Hanoi dialect, it rhymes with the nucleus **-on**, but having a different coda. But quickly looking through the same dictionary, I can't find any examples, so I'm supposing it's infrequent.

I did just find one, the French loan **boong** < *pont* "deck of a ship."

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's strange, though, since <o> usually renders [ɔ]. I wonder if this is a remnant of some pre-reform orthography.

Comment: @jogloran my understanding of the choice of spelling is that orthographic velars are pronounced as labial-velars following orthographic round vowels. in such a case the vowel itself is usually realized as a labializing diphthong. in southern dialects, which have coda mergers, you could get right pronunciation with the spelling **bon**, without resorting to the doubled vowel.

Comment: Right, so in other words, *bong* would be rendered akin to [ɓawŋm] while *boong* is invariably [ɓɔŋm]?

Comment: @jogloran yes, except i would guess that *boong* wouldn't have a labialized coda.

Comment: you can find more examples in Wiktionary, I've just added some in my answer

Answer (score 3):

I'm no linguistics expert but the sound "oong" in the North is pronounced like "on" /ɔŋ/ in Southern dialect. In the South they are both pronounced the same.

For example the word "đoòng" above is pronounced as "đòn" in Southern Vietnam. Some other common words for this are "**[xoong](https://vi.wiktionary.org/wiki/xoong)** nồi" (pot for cooking), "[cải **xoong**](https://vi.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%E1%BA%A3i_xoong) (Nasturtium officinale/Nasturtium microphyllum, a type of vegetable)," "**[boong](https://vi.wiktionary.org/wiki/boong)** tàu" (ship deck), "xe [**goòng**](https://vi.wiktionary.org/wiki/go%C3%B2ng)" (wagon), "[boong-ke](https://vi.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boong_ke)" (from German *bunker* with french pronunciation)...

Comment: I see you answer some question about Vietnamese. It may be good to open a Vietnamese Language Q&A in stackexchange: http://area51.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to make the distinction is that:
 - 'ong' should be rendered as either [awŋm] or [oŋm].
 - 'oong' should be rendered as either [awŋ] or [oŋ]. 
So the difference is in fact the bilabial nasal. The same phenomenon appears in the following pair 'ông' vs dialectal 'ôông'

Comment: there's no "m" in either ong or oong. And there's no "aw" either. If you don't use [phonetic transcription](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet) then don't use [`//` or `[]`](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/301/2313)